# Antlr no viable alternative at input when the keyword is POINT

Tags: antlr4

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.apache.shardingsphere.sql.parser.core.parser.SQLParserExecutor;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;

public class T1 {
    @Test
    public void t1() {
        ParseTree parseTree = new SQLParserExecutor("MySQL", "insert into T_NAME (POINT) values (?)").execute().getRootNode();
    }
}
```

This code will report the following error:

```
line 1:20 no viable alternative at input '(POINT'
```

When I use other column names, it’s all right, but POINT doesn’t work. Why?

Java project, pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.shardingsphere</groupId>
     <artifactId>sharding-jdbc-spring-namespace</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your complete grammar so  that others can reproduce it.

Comment: No need for your pom here, pleas add the grammar you”re using. That is the file that ends with `g4`. Or is the parser part of the sharding-jdbc-spring-namespace dependency?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/shardingsphere/issues/10259

Comment: 10259 from me too. the parser is part of sharding-jdbc-* dependency.

Comment: Yeah,  I posted the link to the issue in case someone want to answer and check if the suggestion was not already provided in the Github issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that all (MySQL), or more, keywords would trigger this error (`POLYGON` probably also produces this error). The grammar probably is trying to match an identifier, but since the input `POINTS` is already matched as a keyword, it fails to match it properly.

Something like this:

```
insert_stat
 : INSERT INTO? table_name '(' column_names ')' ...
 ;

column_names 
 : IDENTIFIER ( ',' IDENTIFIER )*
 ;
```

Looking at the Github issue, one of the maintainers indicated that the 5.0.0-alpha properly handles this, meaning they probably did something like this to fix it:

```
insert_stat
 : INSERT INTO? table_name '(' column_names ')' ...
 ;

column_names 
 : identifier ( ',' identifier )*
 ;

identifier
 : IDENTIFIER
 | POINT
 | POLYGON
 | ...
 ;
```

I.e.: they extended the set of valid identifiers inside the parser.

Comment: I just tested that POLYGON indeed report an error，yeah, it seems to be a bug

Comment: To me it looks as if that project uses an own MySQL grammar. In my grammar this is not a problem at all, since all non-reserved keywords are part of specific identifier rules. Maybe apache.shardingsphere should switch to a more complete grammar?

Comment: Yeah, I tried looking into it on apache.shardingsphere's Github repo, but it has a lot of imported grammars and it was unclear to me which of the (many) grammars was responsible for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Bart's comment [Here](https://github.com/apache/shardingsphere/issues/10259). This bug has been fixed from 5.0.0-alpha.

BTW, ShardingSphere supports many mainstream RDBMS, like MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLServer and Oracle. Therefore you will see a great many g4 files in this repo. Ideally, these definitions in Antlr g4 file are expected to be aligned with the corresponding official SQL docs. So if there is any mismatch, please report that at [ISSUES](https://github.com/apache/shardingsphere/issues). Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, do you know when the official version of 5.x will be released?

Comment: Hi, we are preparing a 5.0.0-beta release which is expected to release this month. So 5.0.0 is going to launch after 5.0.0-beta, I guess that will happen in July or August.